# How to replace a number of similar code blocks with a loop?

Tags: vb.net

Can you please help me to loop this one? I'm starting to learn vb.net language

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Button1.BackColor = Color.Red Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Pink
    End If
    If Button2.BackColor = Color.Red Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Pink
    End If
    If Button3.BackColor = Color.Red Then
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Pink
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide a better explanation than that.  "Loop this one" means nothing.  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of EXACTLY what you're trying to accomplish.  When we don't have to guess, we'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: Also, the title of your question should be a concise summary while the question itself should contain ALL the relevant details.  The fact that you're just starting to learn the language is not relevant in either case.  Just the facts ma'am.

Comment: Sorry, but your question isn't clear take a look at [ask] on how to ask good questions

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either two ways (there are probably other ways) both uses a Foreach loop, which iterates through a collection of object.

First one loops through an anonymous array of the buttons on the form. Then the same condition. Simple enough, if you add another button add it to the end of the array.

```
    For each btn As Button In {Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4}
        If btn.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            btn.BackColor = Color.Pink
        End If
    Next
```

The next method does almost the same thing but you don't have to manually add the buttons to the array. It assumes you want to perform the logic to every button on the form. It takes all the controls (Button's, Textbox's) on the current form, if it's a button, convert it to a button object then perform the same condition.

```
    For each btn As Control In Me.Controls
        If btn.GetType() = GetType(Button) then
            Dim myButton As Button = CType(btn, Button)
            If myButton.BackColor = Color.Red Then
                myButton.BackColor = Color.Pink
            End If
        End If
    Next
```